# message.content.startswith Discord.Py

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    await client.process_commands(message)
    if message.content.startswith('sa'):
        await message.channel.send('as')
```

This is my code. It should say `as` when I say `sa`. It works fine but when I write `salah` or anything that starts with `sa`, it detects it and responds. It shouldn't work like that. I read the documentation but couldn't find anything, I know that it is becuse of `.startswith` but I can't find any replacement for it.

Comment: `It shouldn't work like that` How should it work then? Do you want it to only respond `as` when you type `sa`? Then check equality: `if message.content == 'sa'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As explained in the comments, if you want to compare equality between strings, then:

```
if message.content == 'sa':
```

Answer (score 0):

If the message argument is a string the answer by @TerryA works, otherwise you'll need to read the proper documentation.

Comment: This would be better as a comment on @TerryA's answer, rather than a separate answer.